# Google Apps Script urlfetch causing error 500 when called via google.script.run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sidebar, urlfetch

I am working on a bit larger project part of which is where custom formulas are to be designed, that fetch information related to an ASIN (Amazon Context) from ScanPower.com through urlFetch method of UrlFetchApp in Google Apps script.

The problem is, when I use those custom formulas in spreadsheet as normal spreadsheet function, it works fine and fetch data. If I call it through the menu item, it is still ok.

Now, using the sidebar html having a button to call the same function, the urlFetch used inside the function gives 500 error. This function is being called via the google.script.run.. The same error happens when I try to run it in debug mode from within script editor.

Can anyone help out if it is the Google issue or I am doing something stupid here.

```
function onOpen(e) { 
//menu creation
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
.createMenu('Formulas')
.addItem('Get Data Example', 'showExample')
.addItem('Get Fresh Data', 'queryNetPayout')
.addToUi();
};

function showExample() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('example')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Formulas Configuration')
  .setWidth(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
};
//this is example.html used in sidebar
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<base target="_top">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getFreshDataJS()
{
 alert("data call rcvd");
 google.script.run.queryNetPayout();
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//SCRIPT ends here
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Formula</h3>
<hr />

<form id = "configFormID" name="configForm" role="form">  

<input name="getDataButton" type="button" 
 value="Get Data"  id="getDataBtnID" onclick="getFreshDataJS()" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
//short version of function requiring urlfetch
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function queryNetPayout(query, priceValue)
{
 //for the time being, fixing the input values
 query = "B00KSCABDG";
 priceValue = "";

 var fullData = {
 output: { },
 error: null,
 type: "fresh query"
 };


 var headers = {  
 "Authorization" : "Basic " + scanpKey,//key credentials cannot be shared
 "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
 };

 var params = {
  "method":"GET",
  "headers": headers
  //"muteHttpExceptions" : true
 };
 //this urlfetch stucks when called through google.script.run
 //Or called through debug mode from script project
 //works fine if called through custom formula from spreadsheet 
 //or called through menu item from custom menu
 var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://unity.scanpower.com/net-payout?upc=" + query + "&price=" + priceValue + "&marketplace=US&detail=", params);

var status = res.getResponseCode();    
if(status != 200)
{      
  fullData.error = "Response Code: " + status;
  return fullData;
}

var body = res.getContentText();     

fullData.output = JSON.parse(body);
return fullData;//error = null => successful
};
```